# Adding cmdline (win7) as an Eclipse console view

Tags: windows, eclipse, git, cmd

I've seen it in linux. There's a console you can open that is just a shell. I want the same thing in windows only with either cmd, or with git bash. (MINGW32). I tried googling it but just got flooded with articles about egit and normal git bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have msysgit, you can use it from a regular cmd session:

Launch [`c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k <path\to\your\msysgit>\git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat#L9-L10), and you can type in that cmd windows regular git commands.

**For a bash session**: `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k <path\to\your\msysgit>\git-bash.bat`.

Note that you need to modify those bat:

- `git-cmd.bat`: add a rem before the `setlocal` command, and before the start at the end.
- `git-bash.bat`: add a rem before the `setlocal` command.

So you can add to your Eclipse an **[external tool which will open a cmd in your console](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-open-a-windows-command-prompt-in-my-console.html)**:

[image: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/eclipse/how-do-i-open-a-windows-command-prompt-in-my-console/how-do-i-open-a-windows-command-prompt-in-my-console-03.gif]

Except, instead of calling `C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe` (in the "`Location`" field from the picture above), you could call directly: `C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k <path\to\your\msysgit>\git-bash.bat`.

By 'msysgit', I refer to whatever name you gave to the uncompresdsed portable version of "[Git For Windows](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions)": [download it there](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3&q=portable).

And then you could type git command within the Eclipse console (including a *bash* session)!

---

After testing, the color codes get in the way, even if git works:

- `git-cmd.bat`:
  [image: cmd]
- `git-bash.bat`:
  [image: bash]

Comment: It looks like mysysgit is no different than git for windows. It installs the same package. There's no mysysgit application or directory after installing the latest "mysysgit" from http://goo.gl/ShgU1X. I tried putting the batch file into my git directory anyway and it just opens cmd.exe with no git. I could essentially add git to my system path and just use cmd.exe. I would like the bash commands though.

Comment: @jtsmith1287 sure, msysgit refers to "git for windows" (https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#wiki-what-is-msysgit-what-is-git-for-windows). Unzip a portable msysgit wherever you want (https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3&q=portable), and replace the "`C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`" by the Git bash.vbs I mention in my *edited* answer.

Comment: @jtsmith1287 by "Git bash.vbs", I actually refers to "`<path/to/git>/git-bash.bat`": I have fixed that in the answer. It opens a bash session.

Comment: I've tried several different things this farz and googled more on the information you've provided and the best I can get is either a janky cmd line in console with no tab completion or colors or anything except a bare stdin and stdout, or a normal cmd.exe popping up as a separate window. I've followed your directions perfectly. I'm basically looking for what aptana 3 has, but in eclipse.

Comment: @jtsmith1287 you won't get color or tab completion in an Eclipse console view. I would recommend the `git-cmd.bat` over the `git-bash.bat`. And the Git integration in Aptana isn't always up-to-date, but with my method it wouldn't matter (since you reference the latest Git for Windows you unzip wherever you want).

Comment: Have you tested this yourself and verified that it works? I can not get it to work. I'm on win7.

Comment: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  That's what I keep getting. Using the same path but changing git-cmd.bat to git-bash.bat, so I don't understand why I'm getting that error.

Comment: @jtsmith1287 yes, I have tested it and posted screenshots in the edited answer. You might need to add quotes. And I have revised the way to call those scripts: `C:\windows\system32 /k C:\path\to\git\git-cmd.bat`. You might want to desactivate colors, as they aren't correctly interpreted in the Eclipse console view.

Comment: Not 100% what I was hoping for (can't use bash cmds) but with git added to the system paths it works fine. Thanks for all the effort showing how to make it work. :)